# Style listbox items in c# without changing the item itself

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, listbox

I need to style a listbox item when creating it like so:

```
if (CheckOnline(item)) {
     listBox.Items.Add(item);
     listView.Items.Add(item);
} else
{
     listBox.Items.Add(item + "");
     listView.Items.Add(item + "");
}
```

So basically if CheckOnline returns false I want to modify the look of the item but not actually make the string item + "". Is there a way to make the item display differently from the actual content of that item? I just need some way to signal to the user that the item can't be used at the moment.

Comment: _"Is there a way"_ -- too broad. There's always some way. Your post doesn't include enough detail, and whatever answer could be provided based on what little you have, there are already lots of identical answers on Stack Overflow covering the scenario. You _should_ be using MVVM, with a view model object storing the actual list, your `ListBox` and `ListView` objects bound to that collection via `ItemsSource`, the item view model should have a flag indicating the result of the `CheckOnline()` method, and then your template for the item view model can easily include a style setter for that flag.

Comment: You can use a custom styling for that, but more details are needed here

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying mock an E-commerce service.
So you need to grey out items which are not currently available.

First you need to Have a collection of items in your ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<ItemObj> Items{get;set;}
```

And **ItemObj** should contain a property **IsAvailable**, which should be the result of **CheckOnline()** function.

This collection should be bound to the ListBox/ListView you're using.

You can use a DataTrigger to write a custom style for Items which return false from **CheckOnline()**

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="False">
<!-- Write custom style here -->
</DataTrigger>
```